After initial movement MoveIt2 Servo oscillates under 0 m/s command, ros2_control_node dies when oscillations reach full speed
Using ROS2 Humble. I have a custom prismatic joint and successfully launched MoveIt2 and MoveIt Servo. My joint is a velocity-commanded Joint Trajectory Controller, and path planning and execution works well with my current PID values (no oscillations, moves up to max speed). I am not using MoveIt's C++ API, but rather am launching MoveIt nodes from my launch file.
In addition to trajectory following, I also want to be able to servo the joint with an Xbox controller. When I trigger the servo node to start, it successfully begins, I pull the RT xbox trigger, and the joint moves at the speed I want, mapping the controller axis values to velocity values for the joint. Commands getting published to /servo_node/delta_twist_cmds show up as the speeds I want.
As soon as I let go of the trigger, /servo_node/delta_twist_cmds shows a return to 0 m/s, but the joint begins to oscillate with larger and larger magnitude. I can servo my way back down to 0 oscillations, but as soon as my fingers leave the triggers, the oscillations begin again, always growing. The strange part: Once the joint reaches its maximum negative velocity, the ros2_control_node dies and I'm forced to hit the e-stop since the joint is now moving at full speed toward a limit switch.
Questions

Why is it oscillating despite publishing 0 m/s commands to /servo_node/delta_twist_cmds?
Why would my PID values work for trajectory following, but not servoing?
Why would the ros2_control_node die if the oscillations reach maximum speed?

I really appreciate any help, thank you.

I have no experience with MoveIt2 Servo, but can it be that you run into realtime issues in the servo mode?

How do you interface your hardware? Can you guarantee that your hardware component can run at the desired update rate? ros2 topic hz joint_states gives you an initial guess of the current update rate of the controller manager (inside the ros2_control_node)
Is there any stack trace reported when the node dies? Have you compiled ros2_control from source or installed it from binaries? If you compiled it from source, make sure that you compile with Debug or RelWithDebInfo to make backward_ros work.

